# how to make a file editable in linux without becoming root

Tags: linux, gedit

i am working with files placed in directory /etc/asterisk using vim editor, every time i have to do some editing i have to go to terminal to become root and opens file in vim editor and performs edition,but if i do it by directly opening the file from such directory(/etc/asterisk) in gedit and perform edition in the file but it doesn't show the save option if save as option is selected message becomes "you need to become root for such operation." is there any way to open these files(placed in /etc/asterisk) directly from gedit and save the changes without going into terminal

Answer (score 4):

You can always do `sudo gedit` from the terminal to launch `gedit` as root to edit the files.

Comment: @shehzy Remember to accept the answer if it worked. That's how the StackExchange sites work and make questions/answers available to others in case they have the same problem.

Comment: if using ubuntu, there are some nautilus scripts available that can dodge the command line a bit, such as "Open with your favorite text editor (as root)". Check out the admins tab in Ubuntu Tweak tool for enabling it. then it is simple right click and select the option from within your file manager window.